# Sending and receiving files ( like image, video, pdf ) using socket.io and react JS

Tags: reactjs, server, socket.io, client, chat

I am using socket.io with react JS to create a testing chat app without any DB right now and so far I am able to text a message from one user to another and also able to send an image and display it but I want to know how to send and receive different types of files like pdf or video. If you know please tell me below is my code for sending and displaying image
client side :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const ChatBody= ({ socket }) => {
    const [file, setFile] = useState({});
    const [image, setImage] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("fileUploadResponse", (image) => {

            setImage(`data:image/jpg;base64,${image}`);
        })
    }, [socket])

    const handleFileChange = (e) => {
        console.log("file>>>", e.target.files[0])
        setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    };
    const handleFileUpload = () => {
        socket.emit('fileUpload', file);

    };
    return (
        <div>
            {image && <img style={{ width: '100px', height: '100px' }} src={image} />}
            <div>
                <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} />
                <button onClick={() => handleFileUpload()}>Upload</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
export default ChatBody;
```

Below is the code for server side:

```
//index.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;

//New imports
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const cors = require('cors');

const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors: {
        origin: ["http://localhost:3001"]
    }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`⚡: ${socket.id} user just connected!`);

    socket.on('fileUpload', (data) => {
        console.log(data);

        io.emit('fileUploadResponse', data.toString("base64"));
    })
});

http.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending files via websocket is not a good idea.
It's better to use old good post request.
This is because sending via ws is more complicated on both sides (fronted an backend).
Moreover sending via POST is faster (I tested both variants)